# ios custom calendar view (JT Calendar)

Tags: ios, jtcalendar

I am trying to implement JT calendar in my app. I have copied JTCalendar to my project (did not used pods) and also implemented methods. But I can't see calendar view in my view. My code is :

In my Interface class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarMenuView *calendarMenuView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTHorizontalCalendarView *calendarContentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendarManager *calendarManager;
```

In implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
_calendarManager.delegate = self;

[_calendarManager setMenuView:_calendarMenuView];
[_calendarManager setContentView:_calendarContentView];
[_calendarManager setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

}

My question is how can I connect IBOutlets JTCalendarMenuView & JTHorizontalCalendarView to my views? or is there any other way? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code above is compiling without complaints (in other words, if you have JTCalendar building as a library or framework within your project), you would then drag custom view objects into whatever view you want to add JTCalendar to (i.e. most likely a view within a view controller in a storyboard or XIB file).

Once you have the custom views dragged into position, set the custom class of the custom views to be JTCalendarMenuView and/or JTHorizontalCalendarView.

It's at that point you will be able to drag-connect your IBOutlets in your view controller to the custom view objects.